# Is it possible to select the deepest DOM child in cheerio?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, dom, cheerio

Is there a way to select the deepest child in each branch (specifically divs) in cheerio?

Example:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div>
    <div id="dontSelectThisSinceThereIsADeeperDiv"></div>
    <div>
      <div id="selectThis"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="selectThisAlso"></div>
  <div>
    <div id="selectThisAsWell"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Basically, all the divs that I want to select are the deepest within their "branch" from the parent. Is there a way to possibly do this in cheerio?

Comment: Do you want to find the deepest one in the branches of the `parent` div or this goes recursively?

Comment: Recursively. Basically I would like to get all of the divs that I mention in my example to be selected

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like there is a single function to do what you require. But you can create your own function by utilising different cheerio functions. For a recursive example (not tested, but hopefully you get the idea):

```
function getLeaves(parent, result = []) {
  let children = $(parent).children()
  if(children.length > 0){
    children.each((i, elem) => getLeaves(elem, result)) 
  }else{
    result.push(parent)
  }
  return result
}

let leaves = getLeaves('#parent')
```